# SetCellValueFactory to data object in JavaFX TableColumn

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have a tablecolumn with custom cell render this cell render takes an object and renders its properties as Labels. The problem is that I can't find a way to pass the same object in the arraylist to a column. Here is my code:

```
  //I want to render this object in a column as well as use it in the rest of columns
  CustomerCreationFlow cflow=new CustomerCreationFlow();
        cflow.setId(10L);
        cflow.setFirstName("Feras");
        cflow.setLastName("Odeh");
        cflow.setCustomerType("type");
        ObservableList<CustomerCreationFlow> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(cflow);
        idclm.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CustomerCreationFlow, String>("id"));
//I tried this but it didn't work
            flowclm.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CustomerCreationFlow, CustomerCreationFlow>("this"));
            typeclm.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<CustomerCreationFlow, String>("customerType"));
            flowTable.setItems(data);
```

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement your custom CellFactory by extending TableCell.
In your custom TableCell, you can get the value of the line of the table (logically CustomerCreationFlow) by getting the TableRow of the current TableCell.

That gives:

```
class MyTableCell<S,T> extends TableCell<S, T>

@Override
public void updateItem(final T item, final boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (empty) {
        this.setText(null);
        this.setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        S item = (S) this.getTableRow().getItem();
        // DO STUFF HERE
    }
}
}
```

T is the type of the data defined by CellValueFactory. S is the type of the data representing a row.

Comment: Thanks. this.getTableRow().getItem(); this what I was looking for.